# Python type hint name of enum

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

In Python how can I type hint a variable to restrict it to the names in an Enum?

```py
class DataFormatOptions(Enum):
    calibrate = "Calibrate"
    lrs = "LRS"
    custom = "Custom"


_E = TypeVar("_E", bound=DataFormatOptions)


class DataFormat(BaseModel):
    name: Type[_E]  # <- How do type hint this? It should be either "calibrate", "lrs" or "custom"
    displayName: DataFormatOptions
```

I would like to reuse the names in the enum rather than just duplicating in a Literal such as

```py
name: Literal["calibrate", "lrs", "custom"]
```

Comment: why don't you just use the enum? Ah, is `BaseModel` from `pydantic`?

Comment: Yes `from pydantic import BaseModel`

Comment: `DataFormatOptions` is your type, just like `int` or `str`. `name: DataFormatOptions` should be sufficient. The *display name* seems to be the value you want to have type `str`, but restricted to the actual string values that the enum members have.

Comment: On the API side I want to return `{"name:" lrs", "displayName": "LRS"}`

Comment: @dROOOze I'm using 3.10, `enum.StrEnum` is not an option yet.

Comment: Actually - ignore me - I apparently have no idea what I'm talking about. Deleting the previous comments.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you want to be able to achieve, but `Literal` cannot be dynamically set.

*Edit: Thank you @deceze for prompting me to provide a solution. I'm doing my best to get accustomed to giving good answers!*

- However, we can use `field_validator` to **validate** that `name` meets our criteria. (though not quite type hinting...)

```
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator
from typing import TypeVar

class DataFormatOptions(Enum):
    calibrate = "Calibrate"
    lrs = "LRS"
    custom = "Custom"

_E = TypeVar("_E", bound=DataFormatOptions)
names = tuple([member.name for member in DataFormatOptions])

class DataFormat(BaseModel):
    name: str
    displayName: DataFormatOptions
    
    @field_validator("name")
    def validate_name(cls, incoming_name):
        if incoming_name not in names:
            raise ValueError(f"'{incoming_name}' not in {names}")
        return incoming_name

print("Example 1:")
data = {"name": "lrs", "displayName": "LRS"}
data_format_instance = DataFormat(**data)
print(data_format_instance, "\n")

print("Example 2:")
data = {"name": "anti-member", "displayName": "LRS"}
data_format_instance = DataFormat(**data)
print(data_format_instance)
```

Output:

```
Example 1:
name='lrs' displayName=<DataFormatOptions.lrs: 'LRS'>

Example 2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jibra\Documents\temp\so\sp.py", line 31, in <module>
    data_format_instance = DataFormat(**data)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jibra\Documents\temp\so\venv\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.py", line 164, in __init__
    __pydantic_self__.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=__pydantic_self__)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for DataFormat
name
  Value error, 'anti-member' not in ('calibrate', 'lrs', 'custom') [type=value_error, input_value='anti-member', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/value_error
```